# Building login secured php scripts

Tags: php

So I'm trying to make a secure homepage that checks if you're logged in by getting the text that the user entered on the login page and checking they are correct (so you can't just do www.website.com/home.php to bypass login)

```
<body onload="OpenPhp()">
<form name="GetLogin" action="GetIfLoggedIn.php">
</body>
```

The script is :

```
<script>
function OpenPhp(){
document.GetLogin.submit();
}
</script>
```

the php script should include the username and password vars from the login script and re-check them

```
<?php include "Login.php";
   if($Username === "*****" and $Password === "******"){

// Return To Page

}else{
   //Go Back To Login Page
}

?>
```

But the include statement makes the home page inaccessible. Every time I go to the home page it just sends me back to the index.html page.

Are there any better ways to secure a web page? If so please tell me or explain why this doesn't work,

Comment: 100% there is syntax error in the included php page.

Comment: Never rely on javascript for security purposes. Users can always jsut turn it off.

Comment: @sємsєм The Included Php Page Works Fine Without this script

Comment: You need to close your `<form>` tag with a `</form>`.  Also, what are *posting* in that form?  Are you just using a `<form>` to *redirect* to a PHP site?  Why not just check if they are logged in at the top of `home.php`, when it's loaded?  What's with the `<form>`?

Comment: In `if` statement there is no `and` it should be `&&`

Comment: @sємsєм `and` is valid in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @JohannesH.: It just has a different precedence, so be careful!

Comment: @RocketHazmat I've Tried Both Methods But Neither Work

Comment: What's inside `Login.php`?  What's `$Username` and `$Password`?

Comment: What I usually do on webpages, is `session_start(); if($_SESSION['loggedin']){ } else{ }`.  On the login page, just set `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;` after they are logged in.  When they log out, destroy the session.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I Did $Username = $_POST["UsernameTextboxId"]; And The Same for Password

Comment: @SamTalbot: That's after they login, right?  `$_POST["UsernameTextboxId"]` only exists when the enter it on the form.  When you are on another page, neither `$_POST["UsernameTextboxId"]` nor `$Username` exist anymore.  You *need* to use sessions.  After they login, make a session and set `$_SESSION['loggedin']`, then check it at the top of every page.

Comment: ill also look into sessions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For securing a webpage i encourage you to work with sessions.

You use one script (lets call it login.php) to allow the user to login. If the login is correct you store the username as a session variable.

In your secured pages you just check if the username is set in the session.

In all your scripts you need to execute `session_start();` to make the $_SESSION superglobal variable available.

For logging out you can just destroy the users session using `session_destroy();`

**Examples:**

login.php:

```
session_start();

function isValidLogin($username_, $password_)
{
  if($username_=='sam' && $password_=='secret')
    return true;
  return false;
}

if(isValidLogin($username, password))
{
  $_SESSION['username']=$username;
}
```

your_secured_page.php:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username'))
{
  // display page
}
else
{
  // redirect to login.php
}
```

logout.php

```
session_destroy();
```

Another tutorial i found:
http://www.formget.com/login-form-in-php/

Comment: This seems to be what I need. Can you just clarify what isValidLogon() is?

Comment: isValidLogin($username, $password) is any function to check if the login is correct (by e.g. quering a database).

The name "isValidLogin" is just a placeholder here

Comment: Would The Function Have To Return True For That To Go Through?

Comment: Yes, if the login is valid the function should return true, otherwise it should return false.

I edited my post and added the function.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I'm more adept at c# and java where you have to state return types and stuff. I'm only just starting web development to be honest

Comment: Yes. Php is much less typesafe then java or c# regaring return types, parameter types and variables ;)

Btw: you can accept my answer for this question so its kinda "solved".

Comment: It should also be noted that for a secured login, you should bind the `session_id()` to the users ip (location and other meta data), to help prevent/detect session hijacking.

Answer (score 0):

**You Might Wanna Use This.**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Fetch Array Trick</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","lesson") or die("Connection Not Established");
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $get=array("0"=>$username,"username"=>$username,'1'=>$password,"password"=>$password);
//Created an array above that matches username and password.
$lol = mysqli_query($con,"Select username,password from users");
    while($pre= mysqli_fetch_array($lol)){
        //Now we check if, while in the loop, any tuple matches
        if (($get == $pre)){
            echo '<h1><font color=green>Found</font></h1>';
            //Use JavaScript To Redirect or clear headers to use header("location: dashboard.php");
            exit;
        }
    }
    echo '<h1><font color=red>Not Found</font></h1>';
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<p><label for="u">Username</label><input type="text" name="username" id="u"></p>

<p><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```